# Using Owin in .Net Core for 3rd Party Authentication

Tags: owin, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to use third party sign on authentication in a .net core web application solution I am creating. I am trying to use the Owin package to do so. I have looked at an example of Owin in .net framework, I have been trying to translate this to the .net core application but I have been very unsuccessful.

If someone could point me to an example of a .net core web application that is using Owin for 3rd party authentication it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the the startup file for a framework web application:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;
using Owin;

    [assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(Identity.Startup))]
    namespace Identity
    {
        public partial class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                ConfigureAuth(app);
            }
        }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
                app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")                 
                });
                // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
                app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

                // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
                //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
                //    clientId: "",
                //    clientSecret: "");

               /* app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
                   consumerKey: "",
                   consumerSecret: "");*/

                app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
                   appId: "myid",
                   appSecret: "mysecret");

                //app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
            }

    }
```

I Want to replicate this in .net core now. However, I cannot reproduce the Microsoft.Owin.Security dependency. I have tried Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin.Security and it does not resolve.

Comment: I had the same question. Help would be great for this!!!!

Comment: Yeah, I am researching other options right now.

Comment: Let me know what other options you get.

Comment: I have tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/ but I never was able to implement successfully.

Comment: Oh dude thanks for looking out check these out to https://andrewlock.net/a-look-behind-the-jwt-bearer-authentication-middleware-in-asp-net-core/